# How to render child page component in master page in .Net Blazor

Tags: blazor

I'm trying to render a component which is defined in a base component on all other pages that inherits my base component.

here is a minimal code implementation of my components.

BaseView.razor:

```
 @inherits BaseComponent<TModel,TRepo>
 @typeparam TModel
 @typeparam TRepo  where TRepo : IGlobalRepository

 <!--NotificationView.razor component-->
 <NotificationView VALIDATION_RESULT="Data.ValidationErrors"/>
```

NotificationView.razor:

```
<MudButton  @onclick="@(DisplayNotifications)" Color="Color.Secondary">
   Notifications
</MudButton>
```

Index.razor:

```
@page "/"

@inherits BaseView<LOGS,IGlobalRepository>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.<br />
```

NotificationView component is not rendered at all, am I missing something here? is there a way to make this work?

I'm using .Net 6 SDK

Comment: generally, you can't inherit and extend razor markup. In your scenario, you should use Layout and place the notification in Layout (e. g. MainLayout.razor) or in a root component (e. g App.razor). You can then inject a service class to both, your page and NotificationView to do communication between components

Comment: You could theoretically call `@{ base.BuildRenderTree(); }` in markup of each of your pages.

Answer (score 1):

Would you expect the MudButton above or below the `<h1>Hello, world!</h1>` ?

The fact that you can't control that is the main reason that markup inheritance isn't supported. You can inherit the C# code but not the HTML (razor) part.

And inheritance is overrated, prefer composition. It is much more flexible.

```html
@page "/"
@* @inherits BaseView<LOGS,IGlobalRepository> *@

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<BaseView TModel="LOGS" TRepo="IGlobalRepository" />

Welcome to your new app.<br />
```

or invert it, give BaseView a ChildContent parameter and make it the wrapper:

```html
<BaseView TModel="LOGS" TRepo="IGlobalRepository" >
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  Welcome to your new app.
</BaseView>
```

Comment: it does not matter as I will be placing it top right with css something like position relative top:5px right:5px

Comment: That is a work-around, it doesn't answer the more fundamental question. Nesting and order are important.